# broken push instruction for vm

Tags: c, assembly, hex, vm-implementation

I am developing a virtual machine and have a problem with my push instruction. It pushes an explicit value and not what is held in the referenced register e.g:

```
    0x0064 //this line puts hexadecimal for 100 into register 0
    0x4000 //this is the line i question this will literally put
           //0 into the stack as an explicit value. i want it to
           //put what is in register 0(line 1) into the stack
```

I have included the c source code for my VM below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_REGS 16
unsigned short regs[ NUM_REGS ];

unsigned program[] = { 0x10C8, 0x1164, 0x2201, 0x4200, 0x0000 }; 

unsigned stack[10];
int i = 0;

/* program counter */
int pc = 0;

/* fetch the next word from the program */
int fetch()
{
  return program[ pc++ ];
}

/* instruction fields */
int instrNum = 0;
int reg1     = 0;
int reg2     = 0;
int reg3     = 0;
int imm      = 0;

/* decode a word */
void decode( int instr )
{
  instrNum = (instr & 0xF000) >> 12;
  reg1     = (instr & 0xF00) >> 8;
  reg2     = (instr & 0xF0 ) >>  4;
  reg3     = (instr & 0xF  );
  imm      = (instr & 0xFF  );
}

/* the VM runs until this flag becomes 0 */
int running = 1;

/* push element onto stack */
void push( reg )
{
  int a;

  for(a = 10; a <= 10; i--){
    stack[a] = stack[a++];
  }
  stack[0] = reg;

}

/* evaluate the last decoded instruction */
void eval()
{
  switch( instrNum )
  {
    case 0:
      /* halt */
      printf( "halt\n" );
      running = 0;
      break;
    case 1:
      /* loadi */
      printf( "loadi r%d #%d\n", reg1, imm );
      regs[ reg1 ] = imm;
      break;
    case 2:
      /* add */
      printf( "add r%d r%d r%d\n", reg1, reg2, reg3 );
      regs[ reg1 ] = regs[ reg2 ] + regs[ reg3 ];
      break;
    case 3:
      /* sub */
      printf("sub r%d r%d r%d\n", reg1, reg2, reg3);
      regs[reg1] = regs[reg2] - regs[reg3];
      break;
    case 4:
      /* push */
      printf("push r%d\n", reg1);
      push(reg1);
      showStack();
      break;
  }
}

/* display all registers as 4-digit hexadecimal words */
void showRegs()
{
  int i;
  printf( "regs = " );
  for( i=0; i<NUM_REGS; i++ )
    printf( "%04X ", regs[ i ] );
  printf( "\n" );
}

/* show the stack as 4-digit hexadecimal words */
void showStack()
{
  printf("stack = ");
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%04X ", stack[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

  void run()
{
  while( running )
  {
    showRegs();
    int instr = fetch();
    decode( instr );
    eval();
  }
  showRegs();
  showStack();
}

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
  run();
  return 0;
}
```

im positive that everything else is functional and works well
so please if you can help with my virtual stack problem give me suggestions

Comment: Isn't it simply `stack[0] = regs[reg];` ?

Comment: yes thank you very much this has baffled me for 2 hours im very greatful i should have seen this straight away XD

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry i simply needed to add:
    stack[0] = regs[reg];
as stated by "Jester"